# Possible Stray New Line Character Messing Up Input Redirection to Process

Tags: c#, process, stdin

I'm writing a C# wrapper to execute PAExec with a set list of parameters passed into the method, but hit a snag with redirecting password into the `StandardInput` stream of the `Process` object. Here's the method:

```
public static string RemotelyExecuteExe(string targetIP, string username, string password, string pathToExe, string exeName)
{
    using var proc = new Process();
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "paexec.exe",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        Arguments = @$"\\{targetIP} -u {username} -c -csrc ""{pathToExe}"" ""{exeName}"""
    };

    proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
    proc.OutputDataReceived += OutputDataHandler;

    proc.Start();
    proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
    
    proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(password);
    proc.StandardInput.Close();

    proc.WaitForExit();

    Console.WriteLine($"PAExec returned {proc.ExitCode}");
    return _outputBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Note about output: `OutpuDataHandler` takes each line of the redirected output and appends it to a `StringBuilder` for returning the output to caller for other processing.

**Problem**: what I'm observing is that there seems to be a stray carriage return character in the redirected input stream such that the "Password:" prompt that PAExec prints is immediately passed and then PAExec continues execution with a blank password. This was confirmed by commenting out `proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(password)` and `proc.StandardInput.Close()` and observing that the execution continues to PAExec returning -6 without pausing to wait for input at all. Where could this stray carriage return be coming from?

Comment: Doesn't the documentation exactly explain this `The OutputDataReceived event indicates that the associated Process has written a line that's terminated with a newline (carriage return (CR), line feed (LF), or CR+LF) to its redirected StandardOutput stream.` ?

Comment: That's fine, I'm getting the outputs just fine. The problem is that there seems to be a stray newline in the _input_ stream prior to me putting anything into it, resulting in the "Password:" prompt from PAExec immediately continuing with a blank password and eventually failing the remote execution